# How can I use VBA to read and store the file path, creation data, modified data, and other file information of thousands of files?

Tags: database, vba, excel, ms-access

So, the company I work for stores thousands of lead related files in one folder on a server. In order to improve my workflow, I would like to have all those files (or links to those files) stored in an Excel Worksheet (or perhaps Access, although I've never used it), with information that contain the following:

File name, File path, Date Created, Date Modified

Is there a way to accomplish that using VBA?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you encountering any specific problems such as error messages or lost data?

Comment: To be honest, I am not advanced enough at VBA to even know what functions/objects to look for, and multiple Google searches haven't gotten me any closer to finding out whether or not what I am trying to accomplish is at all possible with Excel.

Comment: Must you use Excel and VBA?   You could use VB.NET and an Excel library like EPPlus.   Using SQLServer file tables might also be a good approach, if that is available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be done with VBA, but it's a lot easier to do it with Power Query, which is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013, and built into 2016 as "Get and transform".

Start a new query "From File > From Folder", select the folder you want. You can edit the query to remove columns you don't need. No coding required.

The query can be refreshed at any time by clicking the Refresh command in the ribbon.

[image]

If you want to use VBA instead, you can check out this macro on my [blog post](http://www.teylyn.com/list-all-files-in-folder-to-excel/).